# whenever browser detect it show the popup only once

Tags: visualforce, javascript

i want whenever i Login salesforce there will be a popup that you are using chrome browser but i want this will popup only once and i tried this code

```
 <apex:page >

    <div id="browserid">

        <script type="text/javascript">

        txt = navigator.userAgent;
        var counter =0 ;
        if (txt.indexOf("Chrome")!=-1)
        {

                text="Chrome"
                window.onload = function(){
                    if(counter == 0){
                        window.alert("Currently you are using  " +text+ "",width=300,height=200);
                    counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
</script>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

but i am getting again and again popup. Please help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: You would need to store somewhere that this user has already had the popup. You could store this information in either a cookie, of in Salesforce. For most use cases i'm  guessing a cookie would be the normal option.

Comment: yes i read about  that but i didnt get how to do with cookie,can u please help me?

Comment: can this is possible with login flow? any body know related to that..!! Any suggestion ??

Answer (score 2):

try session storage.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

when someone logs in  set the key

```
sessionStorage.setItem('Popupshown', 'true');
```

next time onwards check for this key

```
var popupshown = sessionStorage.getItem('Popupshown');

 if (sessionStorage.getItem("Popupshown") === null) {
sessionStorage.setItem('Popupshown', 'true');    
 txt = navigator.userAgent;
        var counter =0 ;
        if (txt.indexOf("Chrome")!=-1)
        {

                text="Chrome"
                window.onload = function(){
                    if(counter == 0){
                        window.alert("Currently you are using  " +text+ "",width=300,height=200);
                    counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: i tried this, and this is working also for me but for this need to clear my browsing data again and again whenever i login,that is not possible.

Comment: it doesnt work that way since session storage only exists for the session and the moment you close the browser window this information is gone. check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523140/html5-local-storage-vs-session-storage.

Comment: Is your requirement to show the popup after every login or only once in the lifetime of the user?

Comment: after every login once in the salesforce for all users.

Comment: Then session storage should work. Please try without clearing the browsing data

Comment: ohk let me try.

Comment: if (txt.indexOf("Chrome")!=-1)
        {
            text="Chrome"
            sessionStorage.setItem('Popupshown', 'true');
            var popupshown = sessionStorage.getItem('Popupshown');
            if(!popupshown){
                window.onload = function(){
                    //if(counter == 0){
                    window.alert("Currently you are using  " +text+ "",width=300,height=200);
                    //counter++;
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
i tried this but now i am not gettting any popup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60585/discussion-between-reddevil-and-sonam-mittal).